# Encontrar valores em uma lista que são iguais ao índice onde se encontram. Como otimizar?

Tags: python, desempenho

Estou aprendendo programação com Python 3.6 e participo de um site de desafios.

Preciso achar o menor número cujo valor corresponde ao seu índice numa lista. Se a lista só contiver um elemento, deve retornar o mesmo. Se houver mais de um elemento que atenda o critério deve retornar 1. Caso não haja tal elemento, deve retornar -1.
Meu código funciona, mas precisa ser otimizado e executar mais rápido, abaixo de 1.5 segundos. Alguém pode ajudar?
Segue abaixo o código.

Grato.

```
def index_equals_value(arr):
    hits = 0
    if len(arr)==1:
        return arr[0]
    for number in arr:
        if arr.index(number) == number:
            hits += 1
            hit_nmbr = number
            if hits > 1:
                return 1
                break
    if hits == 1:
        return hit_nmbr
   else:
       return -1
```

Comment: O enunciado diz como serão fornecidos os valores? Talvez existam ainda mais otimizações que possam ser feitas.

Answer (score 1):

Seu algoritmo tem um bug importante. Da documentação:

> **list.index(x[, start[, end]])**
>
> Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is equal to x

Isso significa que seu algoritmo só compara `number` com *a primeira ocorrência daquele elemento na lista*. Quer dizer, ele falha pro seguinte caso, por exemplo:

```
l = [2, 0, 2]

def index_equals_value(arr):
    hits = 0
    if len(arr)==1:
        return arr[0]
    for number in arr:
        if arr.index(number) == number:
            hits += 1
            hit_nmbr = number
            if hits > 1:
                return 1
    if hits == 1:
        return hit_nmbr
    else:
        return -1

print(index_equals_value(l))  # -1
```

Aqui o `2` na posição `2` satisfaz a condição desejada, mas a comparação sempre acontece com o índice 0, porque é lá a primeira ocorrência do número 2.

Incidentalmente, o `index` também é uma função muito lenta porque verifica a lista toda até encontrar o primeiro elemento passado pra ela. Quer dizer, se você procura por um número `x` e ele ocorre só no elemento 30000000 da lista, o index vai percorrer 30000000 elementos antes de achar e retornar, quando na verdade só precisamos saber se `arr[x] == x`.

---

Medindo tempo de execução:

```
# Criar lista aleatória
import random
l = [random.randint(0, 2000) for _ in range(2000)]
```

-

```
%%timeit
index_equals_value(l)  # Medir tempo de execução da função original
# 27.6 ms ± 2.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

-

```
def index_equals_value_2(arr):
    hits = 0
    if len(arr)==1:
        return arr[0]
    for number in arr:
        if arr[number] == number:
            hits += 1
            hit_nmbr = number
            if hits > 1:
                return 1
    if hits == 1:
        return hit_nmbr
    else:
        return -1
```

-

```
%%timeit
index_equals_value_2(l)  # Medir tempo de execução da função modificada
# 23.7 µs ± 108 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

Como você pode ver, corrigir o bug também acelera a função por 3 ordens de magnitude.

Você deve agora tratar a exceção resultante de um `if arr[number] == number` se `number` for maior do que o tamanho da lista, ou implementar uma verificação para que essa checagem não aconteça. Também não queremos que números negativos sejam contados de trás pra frente, então temos que ignorá-los:

```
def index_equals_value_2(arr):
    hits = 0
    if len(arr)==1:
        return arr[0]
    for number in arr:
        if number < 0 or number >= len(arr):
            continue  # Número não pode satisfazer condição
        if arr[number] == number:
            hits += 1
            hit_nmbr = number
            if hits > 1:
                return 1
    if hits == 1:
        return hit_nmbr
    else:
        return -1
```

Como sugestão do Anderson, também podemos fazer uma solução que itera sob a lista com `enumerate` e compara diretamente o índice ao valor, e não temos que nos preocupar com isso:

```
def index_equals_value_3(arr):
    hits = 0
    if len(arr)==1:
        return arr[0]
    for ind, number in enumerate(arr):
        if number == ind:
            hits += 1
            hit_nmbr = number
            if hits > 1:
                return 1
    if hits == 1:
        return hit_nmbr
    else:
        return -1
```

Comment: E tem um ponto muito importante: se `arr[-2]` for `-2` ele deve contar como ocorrência? Com o seu código isso aconteceria, mas o enunciado não deixa claro sobre isso. Sendo de um site de desafios, que possui exercícios agnósticos à linguagem, acredito que o índice seja considerado apenas entre 0 e len(arr)-1.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ah, boa. Não tinha pensado no caso negativo. Vale a pena fazer a checagem. O `break` foi resquício do copicola, vou tirar também!

Comment: Provavelmente vale adicionar a solução utilizando o `for i, v in enumerate(arr)` para contornar o possível problema com o índice, como uma solução alternativa.

Answer (score 0):

Tentei a solução abaixo para todos os casos levantados pelo `@Pedro von Hertwig` e eles funcionaram instantâneamente:

```
import random
random.seed(42)

def listSearch(x):
    ''' Procura o primeiro índice i tal que x[i]=i.
        Retorna -1 caso não encontre.'''
    for i in range(len(x)):
            if x[i]==i : return i
    return -1

# Caso 1: 
random.seed(2)
l = [random.randint(0, 2000) for _ in range(200000)]
l[199999]=199999
print('O índice é: ',listSearch(l)) # O índice é: 199999

# Caso 2: 
l = [0]
print('O índice é: ',listSearch(l)) # O índice é: 0

# Caso 3: 
l = [3]
print('O índice é: ',listSearch(l)) # O índice é: -1

# Caso 4: 
random.seed(42)
l = [random.randint(0, 20000000) for _ in range(200000)]
l[199999]=199999
print('O índice é: ',listSearch(l)) # O índice é: 873

# Caso 5: 
random.seed(2)
l = [random.randint(0, 2000) for _ in range(200000)]
l[0] = 199999
l[199999]=199999
print('O índice é: ',listSearch(l)) # O índice é: 199999

# Caso 6:
random.seed(2) 
l = [random.randint(0, 2000) for _ in range(200000)]
print('O índice é: ',listSearch(l)) # O índice é: -1
```